# OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space on ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to transfer value of even indexed array(pos) to an arraylist(words), everytime pos has two or more value i get OutOfMemoryError.
Is something wrong? Because I get OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

```
    ArrayList<String> token = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String a : token)
    {
        temp = temp + " " + a;
        pos = a.split("[_\\s]+");

    }
      int c=0;
      for(int i=0; i<=pos.length; i+=2) {
            words.add(pos[i]);
            c++;
    }
```

Comment: How is `pos` defined? what is the content of `token`

Comment: String pos[]=null;
token = word/s

Comment: Show the content of  list `token`. Then only we can solve your `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 2):

In your second `for` loop you don't increment i by 2, you set i to 2, resulting in an infinite loop.

use `i+=2` instead of `i=+2`

There is another problem with that `for` loop: it can occur that `i == pos.length`. In that case `pos[i]` will cause an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Now edited it, error is: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException